# AuthenticationFailedContext.Success() has no effect when handling JwtBearerEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, bearer-token

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API targeting 2.2, and I'm having trouble handling an authentication request in the event that it has failed. The authentication request needs to pass a valid refresh token. My code is handling the failed event when the JWT has expired (I also provide a lifetime validator), and then issue a new JWT and refresh token when the provided refresh token is correctly validated, and thus consumed. However, the pipeline does not continue executing and instead returns a 403 regardless of my code calling `Success()` on the context.

Here is the relevant `Startup.cs` section:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:JwtSecret"])),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            LifetimeValidator = l10n.Api.Code.Auth.Bearer.JwtBearerExtensions.LifetimeValidator
        };
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:JwtAuthority"];
        options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:JwtIssuer"];
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = async context => await context.AuthenticationFailed();
    })
```

And the fail handler:

```cs
public static async Task AuthenticationFailed(this AuthenticationFailedContext context)
{
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(JwtBearerExtensions));

    string refreshToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Defaults.RefreshTokenCookie];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
    {
        logger.LogWarning("No refresh token supplied with invalid JWT, Cookies are {0}", string.Join(", ", context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys));
        return;
    }

    logger.LogInformation("Processing refresh token '{0}'.", refreshToken);

    IConfiguration configuration = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    IUserService userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserService>();
    ITokenHandler handler = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ITokenHandler>();

    long? userId = await handler.ValidateRefreshToken(refreshToken);

    if (userId.HasValue)
    {
        User user = await userService.GetUserAsync(userId.Value);
        refreshToken = await handler.GenerateRefreshToken(userId.Value);
        string jwtToken = BuildJwtToken(user, configuration);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddBearerAuthorization(jwtToken);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddRefreshTokenCookie(refreshToken);
        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(BuildClaimsIdentity(user));
        context.Success();
    }
}
```

When inspecting the 403 result in Postman, I can see the new JWT in the Authorization header, and the new refresh token in the cookie. Those are correctly attributed to the `Response` object. It's just the pipeline that abandons the rest of the processing, and my controller action is never invoked.

How do I allow the request to continue and complete, returning the expected JSON and also issuing (or refreshing) a new auth session?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the correct constructor overload for the `ClaimIdentity` by passing in the authentication type. [More information at this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13041).

For those interested, in this solution, the 403 result happened because of `app.UseAuthorization()`, in which a policy was failing to pass as a result of the authentication issue. In the github issue post, the purpose-built repro did not have this and resulted in the 401 instead.